# Datatables Editor Timestamp Where Clause

Tags: php, sql, datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

I am working with DataTables Editor trying the populate a grid with events from a database which have occurred on the current day. I have tried the following query however come across a problem:

```
// Time
$date = date_create();
$date = date('m/d/Y', date_timestamp_get($date));
// Where Clause
if (isset($_GET['gridNumber']) && $_GET['gridNumber']==2 && isset($_GET['varTodaysActions']) && $_GET['varTodaysActions']=='y') {
    $editor->where($key = date('m/d/Y', strtotime('tblActions.actionTimeStamp')), $value = $date, $op = '=' );
}
```

The issue seems to be comparing formatted unixtime stamps from the database with the current date.  The error I receive is

> {"error":"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '12/31/1969' in 'where clause'","data":[]}

Comment: Looks like `$key` should be the column name (`tblActions.actionTimeStamp`), `$value` gets assigned the date you want to check.

Comment: $key = date('m/d/Y', strtotime('tblActions.actionTimeStamp')) is the column from the database formatted with as 'm/d/Y' date.  The $value is the current date in the same format.  I am not sure why the error occurs because they should be formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The `$key` parameter should be a

> Single field name, or an array of field names

(see [Editor API](http://editor.datatables.net/docs/current/php/source-class-DataTables.Editor.html#356))

This is used as a column name, which obviously does not exist, hence the sql error. Perhaps you can apply the formatting to `$date` variable.

Comment: From what I understand the formatting applied to the $date variable with the following: // Time $date = date_create(); $date = date('m/d/Y', date_timestamp_get($date));  the 'tblActions.actionTimeStamp' variable provides the Json data